# Compilation error dbus-ping-pong

Tags: dbus

I have downloaded files from http://cgit.collabora.com/git/user/alban/dbus-ping-pong.git/tree/

I am trying to compile it using the command

```
gcc pkg-config --libs --cflags dbus-1 dbus-glib-1-2 glib-2.0 -o dbus-ping-pong dbus-ping-pong.c
```

But i am getting the below linker errors

```
/tmp/ccmJkxXb.o: In function g_once_init_enter': dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference tog_once_init_enter_impl'
/tmp/ccmJkxXb.o: In function dbus_glib_marshal_echo_srv__BOOLEAN__STRING_POINTER_POINTER': dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference tog_return_if_fail_warning'
dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to g_return_if_fail_warning' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference tog_value_peek_pointer' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to g_value_peek_pointer' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x109): undefined reference tog_value_set_boolean' /tmp/ccmJkxXb.o: In function echo_ping_class_intern_init': dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x122): undefined reference tog_type_class_peek_parent' /tmp/ccmJkxXb.o: In function echo_ping_get_type': dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x162): undefined reference tog_intern_static_string' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x192): undefined reference to g_type_register_static_simple' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x1a8): undefined reference tog_once_init_leave' /tmp/ccmJkxXb.o: In function echo_ping_class_init': dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference tog_type_class_add_private' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x1e2): undefined reference to dbus_g_object_type_install_info' /tmp/ccmJkxXb.o: In functionecho_ping_init': dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x1fe): undefined reference to g_type_instance_get_private' /tmp/ccmJkxXb.o: In functionecho_ping': dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x21d): undefined reference to g_strdup' /tmp/ccmJkxXb.o: In functionclient': dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x265): undefined reference to dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x2c3): undefined reference todbus_g_proxy_call' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x2d1): undefined reference to dbus_g_error_quark' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x2f1): undefined reference todbus_g_error_get_name' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x305): undefined reference to g_printerr' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x31d): undefined reference tog_printerr' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x328): undefined reference to g_error_free' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x358): undefined reference tog_print' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x363): undefined reference to g_free' /tmp/ccmJkxXb.o: In functionmain': dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x38f): undefined reference to g_type_init' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x3a3): undefined reference todbus_g_bus_get' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x3c7): undefined reference to g_object_new' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x3df): undefined reference tog_type_check_instance_cast' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x3f9): undefined reference to dbus_g_connection_register_g_object' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x406): undefined reference todbus_g_connection_get_connection' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x426): undefined reference to dbus_bus_request_name' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x43a): undefined reference tog_main_loop_new' dbus-ping-pong.c:(.text+0x44a): undefined reference to `g_main_loop_run'
```

Can anyone plz help me to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

gcc -o dbus-ping-pong dbus-ping-pong.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags dbus-1 dbus-glib-1 glib-2.0`

The following comment best explains the problem(Copied from some forum)

"It's very important to list libraries in the correct order. As gcc scans the command line, it pulls in what it needs so far. Each time it sees an object, it adds it to the program. Each time it sees a library, it pulls in only the objects that it needs at that point. You should always list libraries after the objects"

The pkg-config program is used to retrieve information about installed libraries in the system. It is typically used to compile and link against one or more libraries.

If you give only pkg-config --libs --cflags dbus-1 dbus-glib-1 glib-2.0 without any single or double quotes on command line it expands to
-pthread -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  -pthread -ldbus-glib-1 -ldbus-1 -lpthread -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0
so it has all the includes and dependenci libs mentioned after object file