# Undefined references everywhere, while trying to compile BluezTools?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to compile BluezTools using the following command:

```
./autogen.sh && ./configure && make
```

Here is a snippet of the output:

```
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x4d5): undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x4f1): undefined reference to `dbus_g_proxy_disconnect_signal'
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x4fd): undefined reference to `g_object_unref'
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x50a): undefined reference to `g_free'
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x517): undefined reference to `g_object_unref'
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x528): undefined reference to `g_type_check_class_cast'
lib/obexd/obextransfer.o: In function `obextransfer_cancel':
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x56a): undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_is_a'
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x58a): undefined reference to `g_assertion_message_expr'
lib/obexd/obextransfer.o: In function `obextransfer_get_dbus_object_path':
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x5e2): undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_is_a'
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x602): undefined reference to `g_assertion_message_expr'
lib/obexd/obextransfer.o: In function `_obextransfer_get_property':
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x64f): undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x660): undefined reference to `g_type_name'
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x66f): undefined reference to `g_type_name'
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x6a3): undefined reference to `g_log'
lib/obexd/obextransfer.o: In function `progress_handler':
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x4af): undefined reference to `g_signal_emit'
lib/obexd/obextransfer.o: In function `obextransfer_cancel':
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x5ad): undefined reference to `dbus_g_proxy_call'
lib/obexd/obextransfer.o: In function `obextransfer_get_dbus_object_path':
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x619): undefined reference to `dbus_g_proxy_get_path'
lib/obexd/obextransfer.o: In function `_obextransfer_get_property':
obextransfer.c:(.text+0x6e7): undefined reference to `g_value_set_string'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bt-monitor] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/[]/Downloads/bluez-tools-bluez-tools/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/[]/Downloads/bluez-tools-bluez-tools
```

This is my first attempt as building a C project on Linux, where am I going wrong?

Running Linux Mint 15 Olivia 64bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have bluez and obexd installed? https://code.google.com/p/bluez-tools/#Requirements
You could check the output of ./configure for any errors. Usually there is a *configure.log* or similar to grep for erros.

I dont know about Mint package management, but you probably need some kind of obex*-dev package at least or install obex source yourself.

**EDIT** Edited to answer the comment.

I do not think the obexd-client is enough, but try this method and see if it is. Otherwise you need to look for some -dev packages like *libglib2.0-cil-dev* *libglib2.0-dev* and *libdbus-glib-1-dev*. (Those are the names on Ubuntu).

Here is how I got it to compile (still emits warnings, though).

1. Install a bunch of -dev packages for glib and dbus (ddg/google the functions that fail to link, so you see which libraries they are from).
2. Execute `pkg-config --libs --cflags dbus-1 dbus-glib-1 glib-2.0`
3. Use the output of the command in the ./configure e.g.:
   `env  LIBS="-I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0  -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  -ldbus-glib-1 -ldbus-1 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0" ./configure`
4. Execute `make`

See also this question: [Compilation error dbus-ping-pong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171641/compilation-error-dbus-ping-pong)

Comment: I have obexd-client installed that seems to be part of Mint. Is this enough?

Comment: This worked. I'm going to see if Bluez-tools will accept this as a how -to on their site. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed a similar problem by adding `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`. Maybe helps someone.